# Required for dynamically created checkbox using JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have created a checkbox dynamically using vanilla JavaScript. What I am trying to do is, if no element is selected, it should not submit the form.

**Dynamically Generated HTML is:**

```
<form>
    <div id="div_drager">
      <div id="cardDiv_1" class="card p-3 my-3">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <label class="question-input-label" placeholder="Question" id="Question_Input_1">please enter your email</label>
        </div>
        <div id="bodyWrapper_1" class="body-wrapper" required>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_0">
              <input id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_0_checkbox_0" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_0_checkboxOption_0" class="radio-label-label">Option 1</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_1">
              <input id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_1_checkbox_1" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_1_checkboxOption_1" class="radio-label-label">Option 2</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_2">
              <input id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_2_checkbox_2" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_2_checkboxOption_2" class="radio-label-label">Option 3</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="bodyWrapper_1_divCheckbox_6">
              <input id="bodyWrapper_1_divCheckbox_6_checkbox_6" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label id="bodyWrapper_1_divCheckbox_6_checkboxOption_6" class="radio-label-label">Option 6</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

Can anyone help me to identify what went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with tooltip? No `title` attribute, no browser built-in tooltip. Is there some framework / css code in the background generating some fancy tooltip?

Comment: <input type="submit" value="send" title="Sends the form data to server.">

Comment: @PinkeHelga. I mean to say, the required validation is not working in the above code.

Comment: I can't see any validation code as well. There seems to be an issue in your script you did not show.

Comment: btw. I would deactivate the button until the form is filled rather than showing an error.

Comment: i don't want to use that route as my goal is to create checkbox group instead of only checkboxes and write a condition to make sure one is selected. i would prefer that group checkbox should ensure the policies.

Comment: This does not contradict the opportunity to enable/disable the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is ok. There seems to be some issue in your JavaScript validation code you unfortunately did not show.

I recommend as a better approach to enable / disable the button when the form is validated. You can add a delegated `change` event on the `form` element. The events raised from the `input` elements will bubble up to the form.

Here is an example that validates 2 groups of checkboxes. In each group has to be selected at least one.

```js
(()=>
{
  const
    myForm1 = document.getElementById('my-form-1'),
    submit  = document.getElementById('my-form-1-submit'),
    validateMin1SelectedPerGroup = ev =>
      submit.disabled = Array.from(ev.currentTarget.querySelectorAll(':scope fieldset')).reduce(
        (aggr, fieldset) => aggr || fieldset.querySelectorAll(':scope input[type=checkbox]:checked').length < 1,
        false
      )
  ;
  validateMin1SelectedPerGroup({currentTarget: myForm1}); // initialize
  myForm1.addEventListener('change', validateMin1SelectedPerGroup);
})();
```

```html
<form id="my-form-1">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 1:</legend>
    <div id="div_drager">
      <div id="cardDiv_1" class="card p-3 my-3">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <label title="Tooltip" class="question-input-label" placeholder="Question" id="Question_Input_1">please enter your email</label>
        </div>
        <div id="bodyWrapper_1" class="body-wrapper" required>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_0">
              <input id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_0_checkbox_0" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label  title="Tooltip" id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_0_checkboxOption_0" class="radio-label-label">Option 1</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_1">
              <input id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_1_checkbox_1" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_1_checkboxOption_1" class="radio-label-label">Option 2</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_2">
              <input id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_2_checkbox_2" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_2_checkboxOption_2" class="radio-label-label">Option 3</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="bodyWrapper_1_divCheckbox_6">
              <input id="bodyWrapper_1_divCheckbox_6_checkbox_6" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label id="bodyWrapper_1_divCheckbox_6_checkboxOption_6" class="radio-label-label">Option 6</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 2:</legend>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="cb_1"><label class="radio-label-label">Option 1</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="cb_2"><label class="radio-label-label">Option 2</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="cb_3"><label class="radio-label-label">Option 3</label></div>
  </fieldset>
  <input id="my-form-1-submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, One question, what you will do if both Groups have different Ids and one of them is required but not other.

Comment: form example two div with checkboxes
div_drager -- has required checkbox
div_drager_1 -- no required checkbox

Comment: Thank you very much. I have fixed it by excluding unwanted from array.form.

Comment: @Aqdas It's all about code logic. You can write more verbose validation functions as well, e.g. for-loops in the place of the array aggregation function checking for multiple conditions. And instead of excluding from form, you could also surround it with some `<div>` or add some class name to generate a collection from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

So, I removed ids from the following lines in my code and it started working:

```
<div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_0">
<div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_1">
<div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_2">
<div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" id="bodyWrapper_1_divCheckbox_6">
```

But I believe, this is not the solution because having id's may require when you have generated something dynamically.

Following code worked for me but i believe this should not be the right solution.

```
<form>
    <div id="div_drager">
      <div id="cardDiv_1" class="card p-3 my-3">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <label class="question-input-label" placeholder="Question" id="Question_Input_1">please enter your email</label>
        </div>
        <div id="bodyWrapper_1" class="body-wrapper" >
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2" >
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" >
              <input id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_0_checkbox_0" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1" required><label id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_0_checkboxOption_0" class="radio-label-label">Option 1</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100">
              <input id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_1_checkbox_1" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_1_checkboxOption_1" class="radio-label-label">Option 2</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100" >
              <input id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_2_checkbox_2" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label id="cardDiv_1_divCheckbox_2_checkboxOption_2" class="radio-label-label">Option 3</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between py-2">
            <div class="d-flex align-item-center w-100">
              <input id="bodyWrapper_1_divCheckbox_6_checkbox_6" placeholder="" type="checkbox" name="bodyWrapper_1"><label id="bodyWrapper_1_divCheckbox_6_checkboxOption_6" class="radio-label-label">Option 6</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```